# The network works fine but can't ping any address?

Tags: linux, networking, ping

I try to set up my Linux server's network, but the `ping` command doesn't work, although I could use `wget`, it indicated the network is fine, but I can't figure out why the `ping` command doesn't work as it should.

I am using centOS 7.9, here is the network setup information:

```
enp5s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 58.206.100.50  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 58.206.111.255
        inet6 fe80::ec4:7aff:fe32:9d37  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 0c:c4:7a:32:9d:37  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2666737  bytes 4007065931 (3.7 GiB)
        RX errors 12  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 7
        TX packets 1749153  bytes 136913527 (130.5 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xce100000-ce17ffff

[wuzhenqun@localhost ~]$ ping 58.206.96.1
PING 58.206.96.1 (58.206.96.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 58.206.96.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=0.205 ms
64 bytes from 58.206.96.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=255 time=0.170 ms
^C
--- 58.206.96.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.170/0.187/0.205/0.022 ms
[wuzhenqun@localhost ~]$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         58.206.96.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp5s0
58.206.96.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     100    0        0 enp5s0
```

[image]

[image]

I also try the `dig` command, it seems the DNS server is set right.

[image]

Here is the result when I try to ping `intel.com` and `1.1.1.1`.

```
[wuzhenqun@localhost ~]$ ping 1.1.1.1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
144 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 142999ms

[wuzhenqun@localhost ~]$ ping intel.com
PING intel.com (13.91.95.74) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- intel.com ping statistics ---
47 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 45999ms
```

Here is the result of `traceroute 1.1.1.1`:

```
[wuzhenqun@localhost ~]$ traceroute 1.1.1.1
traceroute to 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  gateway (58.206.96.1)  17.524 ms  17.568 ms  17.630 ms
 2  * * *
 3  10.6.20.54 (10.6.20.54)  1.416 ms  1.631 ms  1.644 ms
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

My question is:
Why does the `ping` command doesn't work?

Comment: Please don't post photos of text. They can be hard to read, some people (visual impairments, smartphones, ...) can't read them at all, they are useless for search engines and copy/pasting, and a few other reasons I forgot. Now, your `wget` to Intel succeeds and your `ping`  to Google and Baidu fails, which could mean that you have connectivity to Intel but not the two others. From your DNS server, I conclude you are located in China, so that it is not surprising that Google is blocked. Can you ping something else, for example Intel or 1.1.1.1?

Comment: If your network is up and you cannot resolve address, your problem is a *Name Resolution* problem. If you can resolve addresses (as it appears you can), then your problem is a routing problem. Since you can resolve addresses, but can't ping, it appears you local machine doesn't have a route to your gateway established so it knows where to send the packet so they are routed out to the rest of the world. Your gateway is generally your cable modem/router IP. The simplest way you can establish the gateway address is in `/etc/hosts`, if you don't get it via dhcpcd.

Comment: You need to add to your question which distribution you are using (the version, etc..) and how you are connected to the internet (e.g. direct to cable-modem, through wlan/wifi router, etc..)

Comment: Something between your PC and intel.com/1.1.1.1 blocks ICMP packets, or echo requests or replies. I wonder if traceroute could tell you from which point on the pings don't get any further? Try `traceroute 1.1.1.1`.

Comment: @berndbausch, I just add the result of `traceroute 1.1.1.1` in the question.

Comment: 10.6.20.54 is a  private network IP address (all 10.0.0.0/8 are). Thats probably whats blocking ICMP traffic. Contact that network's admin and ask them about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) Many big providers have ping disabled, so it's not uncommon that ping wouldn't work. 
2.) You have to check your firewall if ICMP packets are allowed, and same on the router side. 
3.) Check if selinux is active in enforcing mode. 
4.) To start discovering a problem start first with pinging localhost, then some device IP in local network, then router IP (up to this point looks like it's working), then IP from the same network of your router, then proceed with actual domain names.  If unsure of your IP (google what is my ip).  And then you can ping some computers from same network (change last 3 digits of IP address).